# How do I replace all occurrences of “</p>” in a string with “” in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I get errors when I try any of the following:

```
str = str.replace(/</p>/gm, "")
str = str.replace("</p>"/gm, "")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The '/' is a special character that you have to escape it within the regex:

```
str = str.replace(/<\/p>/gm, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tr = str.replace(/\<\/p\>/gi, "")
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It is just a line of code. It is not of lasting value to the community as a wiki entry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslash character.

```
str = str.replace(/<\/p>/gm, "");
```

See [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5FpEG/).